# How to programmatically find network data received/sent in OSX with swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I have been trying to make an app that will tell me the data received/sent over network, same data that is available in Activity Monitor.

There is not /proc or /sys in osx, and sysctl doesn't seem to have this stat. Does anyone know how I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This gives a lot of information including package sent and package received

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/netstat"
task.arguments = ["-s"]
task.launch()
```